# Create a table from another table in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table like this:

[image]

I want to create another table, get data from above table and have the result be like this:

[image]

How can I do it? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think you are going to need a column on which to order.

Comment: If the logic is based on the order of records (and it seems that it is), you must have some column to set the order by, since database tables are unsorted by nature.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Can you implement it for me? Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you have an identity or any other column to identify the order

**Sample data**

```
create table test_tab
(id int identity(1,1), sophong int)
insert into test_tab values (7)
insert into test_tab values (4)
insert into test_tab values (11)
insert into test_tab values (7)
insert into test_tab values (4)
insert into test_tab values (11)
insert into test_tab values (6)
insert into test_tab values (3)
insert into test_tab values (11)
```

**Query :**

```
;WITH cte as
(
SELECT *,((ROW_NUMBER() over(order by id)-1)/3)+1 as iden,
         ((ROW_NUMBER() over(order by id)-1)%3)+1 as ident  
FROM test_tab
)
SELECT max(case when iden = 1 then sophong end) as [1],
       max(case when iden =2 then sophong end) as [2],
       max(case when iden = 3 then sophong end) as [3]

FROM cte
group by ident
```

**Result:**

```
1   |2  |3
----+---+---
7   |7  |6
4   |4  |3
11  |11 |11
```